# Where can we get the Nyaya Sutras along with their commentaries in English translation?

Tags: philosophy, translation-request, nyaya, nyaya-sutra

Everyone knows how important the Nyaya Sutras are for Indian philosophy. Indeed, it is impossible to imagine a work of greater influence than this in the history of Indian thought. It is virtually the foundation on which the whole of Indian logic rested.

There are various translations of the Nyaya Sutras available but I am asking specifically for the four volumes published by Ganganath Jha. The reason is that they are perhaps the most comprehensive treatment on this extremely important system of Indian philosophy. They include the English translation of the Bhasya of Vatsyayana and the Vartika of Uddyotakara in full as well as relevant notes from Vacaspati Misra's Nyayavartika-tatparyatika, Udayana's Tatparyaparisuddhi and Raghutama's Bhasyacandra. These volumes were all originally published before to 1919 though they have been reprinted many times in recent years..

Alternatively, another very great treatment are the 5 volumes published by Mrinalkanti Gangopadhyaya which also include the English translation of not only the original Sutras but also the various commentaries on it.

Here are the full names of the books:

*"Nyaya-Sutras of Gautama: With the Bhasya of Vatsyayana and the Vartika of Uddyotakara" by Ganganath Jha - 4 Volumes.*

*"Nyāya philosophy: literal translation of Gautama's Nyāya-sūtra & Vātsyāyana's Bhāṣya : along with a free and abridged translation of the Elucidation by Phaṇibhūṣaṇa Tarkavāgīśa" by Mrinalkanti Gangopadhyaya - 5 volumes.*

Comment: I should also mention here that the 4 volumes of Ganganath Jha are available on Scribd but they are of very bad quality. There were actually various versions available of these on Archive.org but they were randomly deleted even though they were in the public domain.

Comment: I have found the third volume of Jha's brilliant translation of very good quality which I found on StackExchange: http://dspace.vpmthane.org:8080/jspui/handle/123456789/3691 - @SwiftPushkar was the one who uploaded this. If anyone else has the other two volumes available, it would be excellent.

Comment: Come on guys, this is an extremely important book. Most of Indian logic is literally based on this book.

Answer (score 1):

All these books are available on the Internet Archive. Scan quality is good. By the way, though, the book metadata on the site says the language is Sanskrit, but actually, it is English. You can check the pdf! Do not get confused by the Sanskrit tag. Here are the links -

"Nyāya philosophy: literal translation of Gautama's Nyāya-sūtra & Vātsyāyana's Bhāṣya : along with a free and abridged translation of the Elucidation" by Phaṇibhūṣaṇa Tarkavāgīśa" by Mrinalkanti Gangopadhyaya

1. [Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/nyayaphilosophygautamasnyayasutravatsyayanasbhashyamrinalkantigangopadhyayapart1_202003_243_i)
2. [Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/nyayaphilosophygautamasnyayasutravatsyayanasbhashyamrinalkantigangopadhyayapart2_202003_753_i)
3. [Volume 3](https://archive.org/details/nyayaphilosophygautamasnyayasutravatsyayanasbhashyamrinalkantigangopadhyayapart3_202003_809_W)
4. [Volume 4](https://archive.org/details/nyayaphilosophygautamasnyayasutravatsyayanasbhashyamrinalkantigangopadhyayapart4_202003_235_i)
5. [Volume 5](https://archive.org/details/nyayaphilosophygautamasnyayasutravatsyayanasbhashyamrinalkantigangopadhyayapart5_202003_755_b)

"Nyaya-Sutras of Gautama: With the Bhasya of Vatsyayana and the Vartika of Uddyotakara" by Ganganath Jha

1. [Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/nyayasutrasofgautamavol.1mlbd_202003_254_K)
2. [Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/nyayasutrasofgautamavol.2mlbd_202003_569_Y)
3. [Volume 3](https://archive.org/details/nyayasutrasofgautamavol.3mlbd_202003_569_r)
4. [Volume 4](https://archive.org/details/nyayasutrasofgautamavol.4mlbd_202003_357_N)

Happy Reading!